# get url from javascript form, then show in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

my URL looks like "www.google.com/" everything what I need to do is to add a specific word, what I will get from a javascript form, at the end of the url and then show in iframe. 
So if I will enter "test" into a form, an iframe will show "www.google.com/test"
any ideas? Thank you a lot..

```
<form method="get" action="http://slovnik.juls.savba.sk/">
<form action="" method="get" target="_top">
 <input type="text" name="w" id="w" size="20" maxlength="40" value="" />
 <input type="submit" value="Nájdi" /> Stratégia: 
<select name="s"><option value="exact" selected="selected">Presne</option>
<option value="prefix" >Prefix</option>
<option value="substring" >Časť slova</option>
<option value="suffix" >Sufix</option>
</select>
 <input type="hidden" name="c" value="F819" />
```

v: 
    KSSJ4

```
<span title="Pravidlá slovenského pravopisu"><input type="checkbox" name="d"  value="psp" checked="checked"/>PSP</span>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please edit your question so that it contains your HTML (at least form and iframe) and if you have tried some javascript code then include it in your question as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
 var url = document.URL;
 var new_url = url + '/' + new_word;
```

Now append this `new_url` to your iframe like(May be like)

```
document.getElementById('myIframe').src = new_url;
```

Makesure that your iframe id is like `myIframe`

Comment: How do i call iframe then?